# How to safely create files based on session id

Tags: php, session, file-upload

Here is my problem:
I want to make a HTML form to allow users to upload images to my webserver. When the user uploads some files, I want to create a directory for him where the files are uploaded to.

So that the user can delete files later on, I thought I should name the directory as the user session ID...

So here is my concern: I have the chrome plugin 'EditThisCookie' and I can change my PHPSESSID to something like this:

'../test' or any string I want.

Of course I can remove all unwanted characters before I create the directory, but I am very new to PHP and I wanted to know if there are best practices on how to do this correctly?

Update: This is how I do it right now. Is it ok?

```
if(! preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/', session_id())){
    session_regenerate_id();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to use a Session Cookie value for this.

But normally people safe the Session ID together with the remote address (IP) of the user and validate it, so the request needs to have the correct Session Cookie value and remote address.

This way there won't be any unwanted/unvalidated cookie values written to your disk and no abuse through cookie manipulation.

Comment: This looks good. The only problem you may could encounter is, when someone "steals" the ID of another and overwrites or deletes his images.